# Paperclip gem is not working fine with my rails.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 3 and i've installed paperclip gem. I've a form to upload a photo and an image view to display the photo after saving. 
 The problem i faced were,

1. If i'm not including rails.js in my html file, it is saving the file and it gives Completed 406 Not Acceptable error.
2. If i include rails.js in my html, it executes format.js but it is not saving the file.

My code looks like the following:

in _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @image, :url => {:controller => "settings", :action =>         "create"}, :html => {:multipart => true, :remote => true, :method => "post"} do |f| %>
 <% if @image.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
   <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id.to_s %>
<p>
<b> Picture </b><br/>
<%= f.file_field :pic %>
</p>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Upload Image" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Where @image = Image.new in the above form.

in my controller:

```
  def create
   @image = Image.new(params[:image])
   if @image.save
    @user_image = Image.first(:order => "created_at DESC", :conditions =>        ["user_id=?", current_user.id])
   end
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
     render(:create) { |page| page.reload }
    end
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload a file via an AJAX request. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038693/remote-forms-not-posting-paperclip-attachments-rails-3) where this came up.

In this question some options on uploading Files through Upload have been discussed: [uploading a file via ajax with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725888/uploading-a-file-via-ajax-with-php)

I would suggest you look at things like [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

Comment: It was a useful information. Thanks for your suggestion, Tigraine!.