# Rails Paperclip and AJAX form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, paperclip

I have a modal containing a form, in which the user can upload a photo.
Once the photo is correctly uploaded I want to respond via Ajax and display a message.

Unfortunately the form is subbmitted in HTML and Not in JS.

Any idea?

Form code:

```
<%= form_for(Object.new() , :url => {:controller => 'objects', :action => 'create'}, :remote=> true, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
     <%= f.file_field :photo, label: 'add a photo' %>
     <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-success") do %>
            <i class="icon-arrow-up icon-white upload"></i>Upload
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upload a file with AJAX. It's probably the reason why the submit is in HTML and not in JS.

Nevertheless you have some hack to solve this problem:

- HTML5: http://www.queness.com/post/11434/7-javascript-ajax-file-upload-plugins
- Flash: http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/
- iframe method: http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%2Biframe%2Bupload

I hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately rails cannot upload files directly with ajax, as javascript does not have direct access to to hard drive files. Apparently there's a workaround involving iframes: this previous question may help you:

[RAILS - paperclip don't work with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829238/rails-paperclip-dont-work-with-ajax?rq=1)

and a bit on file uploading in rails forms:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-ajax