# form_for :remote => true doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a form:

```
=form_for @user, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true do |f|
  %h2.underline= t('edit-profile-picture')
  %p=t('upload_message')
  .flexbox.flex-center
    .btn.btn-default{:onclick => 'upload()'}= t('choose-file')
    = f.file_field :avatar, :style => 'visibility: hidden; position: absolute'
```

Which is being submitted by a script when user choses a file.

```
$("input:file").change(function (){
    $('#edit_user_2').submit();
});
```

Everything goes well, exscept of one thing - the console says:

```
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
```

Obviously, I'm getting a response in accordance with `format.html` in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html {redirect_to user_path}
end
```

The weirdest thing, it perfectly works with my another `form_for` (which is pretty simple) in another controller.

```
=form_for @suggestion, remote: true do |f|
      .col-sm-12
        .form-group
          %label.control-label{:for => 'name'}= t('your-suggestion')
          = f.text_area :content, :placeholder => t("suggestion-example"), :class => "form-control"
      .row.container-margin
        .col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-10
          = f.submit t("send"), :class => "btn btn-default"
```

As expected, console says:

```
Processing by SuggestionsController#create as JS
```

I've already tried to force `:format => :js` like that:

```
=form_for @user, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal", 'data-type' => 'js'}, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true, :format => :js do |f|
```

It gives a weired result:

```
Processing by UsersController#update as JS
...
Rendered users/update.js.erb (0.0ms)
```

But it renders as a raw file!

So, it seems like my `remote: true` doesn't work for some reason. Any ideas why? Just one thing comes on my mind: User model is created and used by the Devise gem, but I'm not sure how's it connected with my problem :(

UPD:

Yes, I do have `jquery_ujs` in my `application.js` manifest. Here it is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

UPD2:

I tried to get rid of my JavaScript `upload()` function and use a classical `input`, but it gave the same result.

Comment: have you added `jquery-ujs` to your application.js manifest file?

Comment: As I said above, :remote => true works perfectly with another controller in the same application. So, yeah, of couse I have `jquery-ujs` in my manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're prepared to forgo your standard HTML form functionality (IE make the form ajax & file upload only), you'll be able to use [`jquery-file-upload`](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails).

We've used this in several implementations, to provide ajax upload functionality:
[image]

[image]

This works using the `jquery-file-upload` plugin, the code for which you can see here.

--

In short, if you use the plugin, you'll have to bind the upload form to the `.fileupload()` function:

```
$('#avatar').fileupload({

    url: '/profile/' + $(this).attr('data_id'),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',

    add: function (e, data) {
        //$(".items .avatar .avatar").prepend('<div class="loading" id="avatar_loading"><img src="<%= asset_path("profile/avatar_loading.gif") %>"></div>');
        //$('#avatar_loading').fadeIn('100');
        $(this).avatar_loading('avatar_loading');
        data.submit();
    },
    success: function (data, status) {;
        $("#avatar_img").fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).attr("src", data.avatar_url).fadeIn('fast', function(){
                $(this).avatar_loading('avatar_loading');
            });
        });
    }

});
```

If you need specific code for your app, I'll gladly write an update.

Answer (score -1):

You can't upload a file with AJAX. It's probably the reason why the submit is in HTML and not in JS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13626557/5381547

Comment: [JQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) addresses the issue :)